# Having confusion with pathing in Django templates

Tags: django

When I use the `url(r'^consultar/$', 'rcb.core.views.consultar'),` in browser `http://localhost:8000/consultar` the `consultar.html` file find the `jquery-1.11.2.min.js` file, appearing the following information:

```
Remote Address:127.0.0.1:8000
Request URL:http://localhost:8000/static/js/jquery-1.11.2.min.js
Request Method:GET
Status Code:200 OK
```

But when I use the `url(r'^proposta/consultar/$', 'rcb.core.views.consultar'),` in browser `http://localhost:8000/proposta/consultar/` the `consultar.html` file not find the `jquery-1.11.2.min file.js`. Appearing the following error:

```
Remote Address:127.0.0.1:8000
Request URL:http://localhost:8000/proposta/static/js/jquery-1.11.2.min.js
Request Method:GET
Status Code:404 NOT FOUND
```

Could someone help me fix the code to run the url `http://localhost:8000/proposta/consultar/`

Below is the code and the structure of files and directories:

**consultar.html**

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
....
```

**base.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <script src="../static/js/jquery-1.11.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>
    {% block corpo %}{% endblock %}
</body>
</html>
```

**views.py**

```
def consultar(request):
    propostas_salvas=search()
    return render_to_response('consultar.html', { 'propostas_salvas' :  propostas_salvas}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

My structure of files and directories is:

```
rcb (Project)
    core (is the App)
        static
            js
                jquery-1.11.2.min.js
        template
            base.html
            consultar.html
        views.py
        ...
        ...
        ...
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use path to javascript relative to your domain, not to document you're requesting, because for each document relative path to javascript would be different. So change that line:

```
    <script src="../static/js/jquery-1.11.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

into:

```
    <script src="/static/js/jquery-1.11.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Or even better, load static in your template and use static file management built into django:

```
    <script src="{% static "js/jquery-1.11.2.min.js" %}" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

That way you can change later your `STATIC_URL` in settings and django will correct path to your static files. Even if they are on different domain (some CDN or no-cookie domain just for your static files).